# dropping partition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, database-partitioning

I am kinda lame in mysql, but I need it for running Zabbix.
Due to large DB, I am using a partitioning, based on script below.

> https://bestmonitoringtools.com/zabbix-partitioning-tables-on-mysql-database/
> (full script on the end of the page)

What I have, is just a minor issue. I have more partitions created by this script, than I really need. Its not by script fault, it has been done due high number of partition specified before.

So, I am using only first 31 partitions, which are overwritten by new data.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION, TABLE_ROWS, PARTITION_METHOD        FROM information_schema.PARTITIONS         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'zabbix' AND TABLE_NAME = 'history_uint';
+----------------------------+------------+------------------+
| PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION | TABLE_ROWS | PARTITION_METHOD |
+----------------------------+------------+------------------+
|                          1 |   72866976 | RANGE            |
|                          2 |   72006233 | RANGE            |
|                          3 |   72172620 | RANGE            |
|                          4 |   71750837 | RANGE            |
|                          5 |   72436805 | RANGE            |
|                          6 |   70060071 | RANGE            |
|                          7 |   72177768 | RANGE            |
|                          8 |   72818115 | RANGE            |
|                          9 |   72506332 | RANGE            |
|                         10 |   70107634 | RANGE            |
|                         11 |   72412529 | RANGE            |
|                         12 |   72569999 | RANGE            |
|                         13 |   72017589 | RANGE            |
|                         14 |   72199641 | RANGE            |
|                         15 |   70607394 | RANGE            |
|                         16 |   72936268 | RANGE            |
|                         17 |   72417441 | RANGE            |
|                         18 |   72442571 | RANGE            |
|                         19 |   72050858 | RANGE            |
|                         20 |   72011472 | RANGE            |
|                         21 |   72023456 | RANGE            |
|                         22 |   72575896 | RANGE            |
|                         23 |   71883021 | RANGE            |
|                         24 |   72475875 | RANGE            |
|                         25 |   72492657 | RANGE            |
|                         26 |   72040893 | RANGE            |
|                         27 |   72115739 | RANGE            |
|                         28 |   72122055 | RANGE            |
|                         29 |   71615232 | RANGE            |
|                         30 |   72075029 | RANGE            |
|                         31 |   23110328 | RANGE            |
|                         32 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         33 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         34 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         35 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         36 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         37 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         38 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         39 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         40 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         41 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         42 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         43 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         44 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         45 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         46 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         47 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         48 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         49 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         50 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         51 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         52 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         53 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         54 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         55 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         56 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         57 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         58 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         59 |          0 | RANGE            |
|                         60 |          0 | RANGE            |
+----------------------------+------------+------------------+
60 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

complete

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,PARTITION_NAME,PARTITION_DESCRIPTION,PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION,PARTITION_METHOD,PARTITION_EXPRESSION,CREATE_TIME,UPDATE_TIME FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='zabbix' AND TABLE_NAME = 'history_uint' AND PARTITION_NAME IS NOT NULL;
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+------------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME   | PARTITION_NAME | PARTITION_DESCRIPTION | PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION | PARTITION_METHOD | PARTITION_EXPRESSION | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+------------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105050000  | 1620252000            |                          1 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-06 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105060000  | 1620338400            |                          2 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-07 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105070000  | 1620424800            |                          3 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-08 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105080000  | 1620511200            |                          4 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-09 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105090000  | 1620597600            |                          5 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-10 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105100000  | 1620684000            |                          6 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-11 00:00:02 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105110000  | 1620770400            |                          7 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-12 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105120000  | 1620856800            |                          8 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-13 00:00:02 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105130000  | 1620943200            |                          9 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-14 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105140000  | 1621029600            |                         10 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-15 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105150000  | 1621116000            |                         11 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-16 00:00:12 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105160000  | 1621202400            |                         12 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-17 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105170000  | 1621288800            |                         13 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-18 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105180000  | 1621375200            |                         14 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-19 00:00:02 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105190000  | 1621461600            |                         15 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-20 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105200000  | 1621548000            |                         16 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-21 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105210000  | 1621634400            |                         17 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-22 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105220000  | 1621720800            |                         18 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-23 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105230000  | 1621807200            |                         19 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-24 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105240000  | 1621893600            |                         20 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-25 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105250000  | 1621980000            |                         21 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-26 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105260000  | 1622066400            |                         22 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-27 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105270000  | 1622152800            |                         23 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-28 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105280000  | 1622239200            |                         24 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-29 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105290000  | 1622325600            |                         25 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-30 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105300000  | 1622412000            |                         26 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-05-31 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202105310000  | 1622498400            |                         27 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-01 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106010000  | 1622584800            |                         28 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-02 00:00:02 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106020000  | 1622671200            |                         29 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-03 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106030000  | 1622757600            |                         30 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 00:00:01 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106040000  | 1622844000            |                         31 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106050000  | 1622930400            |                         32 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106060000  | 1623016800            |                         33 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106070000  | 1623103200            |                         34 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106080000  | 1623189600            |                         35 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106090000  | 1623276000            |                         36 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106100000  | 1623362400            |                         37 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106110000  | 1623448800            |                         38 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106120000  | 1623535200            |                         39 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106130000  | 1623621600            |                         40 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106140000  | 1623708000            |                         41 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106150000  | 1623794400            |                         42 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106160000  | 1623880800            |                         43 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106170000  | 1623967200            |                         44 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106180000  | 1624053600            |                         45 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106190000  | 1624140000            |                         46 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106200000  | 1624226400            |                         47 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106210000  | 1624312800            |                         48 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106220000  | 1624399200            |                         49 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106230000  | 1624485600            |                         50 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106240000  | 1624572000            |                         51 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106250000  | 1624658400            |                         52 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106260000  | 1624744800            |                         53 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106270000  | 1624831200            |                         54 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106280000  | 1624917600            |                         55 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106290000  | 1625004000            |                         56 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202106300000  | 1625090400            |                         57 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202107010000  | 1625176800            |                         58 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202107020000  | 1625263200            |                         59 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
| def           | zabbix       | history_uint | p202107030000  | 1625349600            |                         60 | RANGE            | `clock`              | 2021-06-04 03:30:02 | 2021-06-04 08:09:21 |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+------------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
60 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Is there any way, to delete partitions 32-60?

Comment: How to deal wihth partitions is explained in the manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html)   (HINT: search for `DROP PARTITION` on that page)

Comment: See complete SHOW CREATE TABLE output - it includes partitions parameters. You need RANGE definition. Ensure that you don't want to delete the partition with LESS THAT MAXVALUE, if it is then exclude if from your list. Then make complete backup of this table and check it for consistency. And finally perform according ALTER TABLE DELETE PARTITION statement.